# Efficient way to count Hamiltonian paths in a grid graph for a given pair of vertices

Tags: graph-theory, co.combinatorics

1. What algorithm would you use to count all the Hamiltionian paths in a $n \times m$ grid graph ($n$ and $m<10$) from a given starting vertex to an ending one?
2. How can you determine if this grid graph has holes?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: On such a small graph, even the most naive algorithm would be fast, so I wouldn't bother with efficiency (unless you're trying to do this by hand!)

Comment: @Thierry Zell: Is that true?  Setting n=m=9 yields a graph with 81 vertices and maximum degree 4, and I am not so sure that naive algorithms will be fast for graphs of this size.

Comment: Then answer is sometimes zero. Color the vertices like a chessboard. If there are an odd number of vertices you can't start and end on a white vertex.

Comment: Alon Itai, Christos H. Papadimitriou, and Jayme Luiz Szwarcfiter,
"Hamilton Paths in Grid Graphs,"
*SIAM J. Comput.* Volume 11, Issue 4, pp. 676-686:
"...we give necessary and sufficient conditions for the graph to have a Hamilton path between these two nodes."

Comment: I think I remember having been told the Hamiltonian Path problem was NP-Hard on subgraphs of grids... If you are interested in this, I know who to ask for references. Your question is about computing the number of them, so it's not an answer but I thought I may mention it, just in case ...

Comment: @Nathann Cohen: That is one of the results shown in the paper by Itai, Papadimitriou and Szwarcfiter which Joseph O'Rourke cited.

Comment: For Mathematica's treatment of the problem and references see:
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HamiltonianPath.html

Answer (score 4):

Here is Mathematica code that finds all the Hamiltonian paths between opposite
corners of a $5 \times 5$ grid graph:

```
<< Combinatorica`;
n = 5;
G = GridGraph[n, n];
(* Add dangling edges to corners to force start/end vertices *)
Gplus = AddVertex[G, {0, 0}];
Gplus = AddVertex[Gplus, {n + 1, n + 1}];
Gplus = AddEdge[Gplus, {1, n^2 + 1}];
Gplus = AddEdge[Gplus, {n^2, n^2 + 2}];
ShowGraph[Gplus]
H = HamiltonianPath[Gplus, All];
Print["Number of paths=", Length[H]];
Print["Paths=", H];
Number of paths=208
Paths={{26,1,2,3,4,5,10,9,8,7,6,11,12,13,14,15,20,19,18,17,16,21,22,23,24,25,27}, [etc.]}
```

[image: GridGraph]

---

**Addendum**.  Setting $n=7$ to compute the comparable number for a $7 \times 7$ grid
returns 223,424 Hamiltonian paths between opposite corners. [5 hrs computation time on a 2.5GHz laptop.]
The first one returned is:

```
{50, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 15, 16, 17, 18,
19, 20, 21, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35,
42, 41, 40, 39, 38, 37, 36, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 51}
```

Comment: Would you by any chance know how the Hamiltonian Path problem is solved in Mathematica ? I found the source of the Combinatorica package [1], and the HamiltonianPath seems to call the HamiltonianCycle function, but I have to admit I do not really understand what is going on in this function. It looks too short to be anything more complicated than a bruteforce enumeration, but I am having a very hard time with their syntax ^^;

THanks

[1] http://www.cs.uiowa.edu/~sriram/Combinatorica/NewCombinatorica.m

Comment: @Nathann:  Sorry, I don't know offhand, but I suspect *Combinatorica* follows F. Rubin, "A Search Procedure for Hamilton Paths and Circuits," *J. ACM* 21, 576-580, 1974. 